# Notification box at bottom page

Tags: notifications

I wonder if you can recommend any scrip which can show the notification box at the bottom of the page – similarly to how it is done in Bloomberg Terminal:

https://bizlib247.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/bb-wei.png

https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XcYv1Pmjd8I/hqdefault.jpg

I would need this notification box to be able to show HTML content.
Cheers!
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean on an actual html page, because bloomberg controls the carousel and isn't going to let you put things down there without paying, (ie. bloomberg pursuits advertisement, or things it wants to highlight like the Tradebook charity day) and the terminal isn't written in html, but on your page you could add a div tag in your html:

```
<div id="bloombergbar">
    html here...
</div>
```

then style the css:

```
#bloombergbar {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #fde073;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2.5;
    overflow: hidden; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    -moz-box-shadow:    0 0 5px black;
    box-shadow:         0 0 5px black;
}
```

Comment: Fnatastic - thank you so much for your help- - I created a fiddle with this script:  https://jsfiddle.net/Line7/gLr9k9m2/3/

Comment: You sound like you have worked at Bloomberg)) great to find someonw knowledgable - yes I need this for a html page - actually a whole site - i will put and Iframe inside this did and can make it empty or fill with any content when needed - I was thinking of using the running TICKER but it adds unnecessary visual noise....you think an iframe inside this div can contain the responsive content which will respond when the master page is shrinked?

Comment: BTW - you must know this - these ads at Bloomberg appear sporadically and can be closed by users? or they are turned off automatically after they have been seen by the clients?

Comment: They rotate at the bottom of the terminal and then when clicked take you to the ad page, sometimes within the terminal, sometimes outside. It sounds like you have what you need, do you mind marking the question answered?